# in java check if in a array there is a number which is greater than every numbers before it and smaller than all after it, the numbers are in order

Tags: java, arrays

First i wanted to apologize if i could not say all the details in the title because the number of characters i needed to express my problem were beyond the limited range.
here you can see the details:

I want to write a program in java that first gets the integer  n and then gets n integer numbers ( x1,x2, …,xn) and in the output tells if any i exists such that : (i can be equal to n)
X1<=x2<=x3<=…<= xi > …> xn     or    X1=>x2>=x3>=…>= xi < …< xn
For example:

```
Input:
5
1 
2 
5
3
1 
Output:
Yes
```

above n is equal to 5 which is the first number and the next 5 numbers are elements of the array. in this example the following condition is met :
x1 < x2 < x3 > x4 > x5 because 1 < 2 < 5 > 3 > 1 and it is obvious that i is 3

```
Input:
4
1
2
5
9
Output:
Yes
```

in the previous example i was equal to n . both of them are 4. and

x1 < x2 < x3 <x4

```
Input:
7
1
8
5
6
7
2
6 
output:
No
```

here n is 7 but the conditions ( X1<=x2<=x3<=…<= xi > …> xn     or    X1=>x2>=x3>=…>= xi < …< xn) are not met  because: 1 < 8 > 5 < 6 < 7 > 2 < 6
so the output must be No

the following code is what i expected to work but i  do not get the right answer ( it keeps showing No in the output even when it should be showing Yes)

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner  input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" enter n ");

        byte n = input.nextByte();

        boolean isConditionMet = true;

        int[] heights = new int[n];

        System.out.println("enter elements of your array ");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

            heights[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

            for ( int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++){

                if ( heights[j-1] <= heights[j]) {

                    for (int k = i; k < n; k++) {


                        if (heights[k - 1] > heights[k]) {

                            isConditionMet = true;
                        } else {

                            isConditionMet = false;
                        }

                    }
                }

                else {

                    for ( int k = i ; k <n ; k++){

                        if ( heights[k-1] < heights[k] ){

                            isConditionMet = true;
                        }

                        else {

                            isConditionMet = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ( isConditionMet ){

            System.out.println("Yes");
        }

        else{

            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to explain the whole problem in the title, but give a short summary for people to get *an idea* what kind of problem your question is about ... For example you basically want to know how to fix your ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException so something like "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while looking for specific number in array" would work ...

Comment: You said "in the previous example `i` was equal to `n` . both of them are 9."  

No it's not.  `n` is equal to 4.  It's always equal to 4.  Do you mean `height[i]  == 9` when `i` == `n`?

Comment: Please explain how the first and last examples yield the the shown outputs.

Comment: yes yes you are right i made a mistake there the true form was "i equals n equals 4" i just edited that. thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 0):

Your last loop starts like this:

```
for ( int k = i ; k <=n ; k++){
```

This will loop up to **an including** the value `n` (3 in the case that you mention). An array of 3 elements **does not have an index 3**, the valid indices are 0, 1 and 2.

Note how your first two loops use `i < n` as the end condition? That's the correct way, because you have to stop when executing the loop body when you reach `n`.

Comment: thanks i eliminated "=" and it does not give me that error but now it gives me the wrong answer that i have no idea why now i update my code above